# For each loop results in duplicate post display when post has more than one category

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, foreach, duplicates

I have the following code:

```
<div class="documents-posts">
    <?php if (!empty($posts)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
            <?php set_query_var( 'taxonomy', $taxonomy ); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('document'); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

which works fine as long as each post has only one category. When I assign a second category to a post the post is displayed twice. If I make it have 3 categories the post is displayed triple… Why?

**Update:**
Declaration $posts variable

```
$post_type = 'press-release';
$taxonomy = 'press-release-types';
$categories = $xxxxxx->get_categories($taxonomy);
$posts = $xxxxxx->get_posts_ordered_by_categories($post_type, $taxonomy, $categories);

set_query_var( 'posts', $posts );
set_query_var( 'categories', $categories );
set_query_var( 'taxonomy', $taxonomy );
```

**Update 2:** From Helper php

```
public function get_posts_ordered_by_categories($post_type, $taxonomy, $categories) {
    $posts = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category_posts = $this->get_posts_from_category($post_type, $taxonomy, $category->term_id);
        $posts = array_merge($posts, $category_posts);
    }
    return $posts;
}

protected function get_posts_from_category($post_type, $taxonomy, $category_id) {
    return get_posts([
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => (int) $category_id,
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'suppress_filters' => false,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: How do you declare the $posts-variable? WP_Query? get_posts() ?

Comment: @ninja: I hope this helps. I am not a php pro…

Comment: Wherever `get_posts_ordered_by_categories` comes from, I think showing duplicates is the valid behavior for this (if a post belongs to two or more categories and the viewer looks at one specific category, he's supposed to find all desired posts there). If you don't want this behavior, you have to filter out duplicates yourself. Why are you using this `get_posts_ordered_by_categories` in the first place instead of just querying all 'press-release' type posts?

Comment: It is an undesired behavior as I see it. As I have a filtering above with categories. Why should I want to display the same post twice? And a post that has 2 categories should be in the results when filtering one or the other category. But not 2 times filtering for each (or even not filtering, at all). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Damocles: see my update 2… Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get_posts_ordered_by_categories` you're getting all posts from the category and put it in posts array. You have to check if post is existing in that array. For example:

```
public function get_posts_ordered_by_categories($post_type, $taxonomy, $categories) {
    $posts = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category_posts = $this->get_posts_from_category($post_type, $taxonomy, $category->term_id);
        foreach ($category_posts as $post) {
            $posts[$post->ID] = $post;
        }
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

That way you'll get list of unique posts.

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried this function, but it throws a “critical error” (within the second loop inside as it seems)

Comment: I don't know exactly what ```get_posts_category``` returns. Can you post result of ```print_r($this->get_posts_from_category)```?

Comment: Sorry my ignorance. Where do I put this “print_r…” line in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function get_posts_ordered_by_categories($post_type, $taxonomy, $categories) {
    $posts = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category_posts = $this->get_posts_from_category($post_type, $taxonomy, $category->term_id);
       print_r($category_posts);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

post the results of this code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, much appreciated, but I can’t do that :-( First: because it’s about 2 meters long, second it contains my clients data which I cannot put in public. It starts with: Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 2810 [post_author] => 8 [post_date] => 2019-09-18 21:45:20 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-09-18 19:45:20 [post_content] => [post_title] => …

Comment: I forgot to write that I need just a sample of this. Sample that you provided is enough. I edit my first answer. It should work now.